# Change product image based on bundled item selected

Tags: magento-community

the site I am building sells vanities

Using bundled products they want to display a different picture as the customer selects bundled items

Page loads, it shows a base image

- Customer has option to select faucet, sink and cabinet
- Customer selects Faucet 2, image changes to faucet 2 base 1 sink 1 (I will have images created for each scenario
- Customer selects Sink 4, image changes to Faucet 2 base 1 sink 4 (again, image is created with this selection)

I have looked for modules that does this with no luck... any ideas would be welcome

Magento 1.8 (going to 1.9 soon)

Answer (score 1):

You'd be hard pressed to get an out-the-box module to do this. It is very custom/specific to your sites design / functionality.

It would not be very difficult to implement this.

Attach a javascript change event listener to the option element(s).

That would then trigger some custom javascript: (be it vanilla js, jquery or prototype):

The resulting code would build the correct image URL, based on the param(s) that was selected on the element, and passed to the routine. You can even add in your own data-properties to the elements, and use those.

The image tag `src` property gets changed to the adjusted image URL.
Using jQUery, something as simple as this would do that: `$('#my_image').attr('src','<YOUR BUILD URL>');`

The end result would be that the image adjusts as options are selected.

Comment: [this module](http://getsome.mojomage.com/bundled-mojo-v2.html) suits the specific needs of the site, but not the exact want of the client...  If I cant talk the client into this I will try your idea... thank you